# how to run a batch file in php under xampp on windows

Tags: php, svn, batch-file

I'm trying to write a little php to update an svn repo on a server running xampplite under windows. (This is a development server, not a production one.)

Here's my php:

```
<?php
passthru("update.bat"); 
// I also tried exec() & putting the svn command in directly
?>
```

update.bat is sitting in the same folder as the php script

Here's the content of update.bat:

```
svn up c:\path\to\my\repo
```

When I run the batch file by itself, it works. When I run it via php, I get this printed to the browser:

```
C:\path\to\script\folder>svn up c:\path\to\my\repo
```

which looks good, but the project isn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the username and password to the batch made the difference. Here's the new `update.bat`:

```
svn up --username <usr> --password <pwd> c:\path\to\the\repo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#85930) tip on php.net/function.exec

Comment: I can get it to run a simpler batch file (e.g. 'echo hi'), but the svn update is still eluding me.

Comment: Sounds like something's screwy in your environment. Try comparing the phpinfo() for your command-line environment to the phpinfo() for the web process.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to [manually compile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php) the [php svn extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) (there's no Windows DLL), but you also need the svn libraries first.

Comment: I sure hope I can avoid that solution. (Seems like overkill.)